# Maven is suddenly throwing error, Truncated class file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

Yesterday Maven is working fine,,today it shows that problem,I tried backup also it does not work ,and for your information tomcat is working fine its a maven problem ,and I uninstall maven and install it again and all things before posting this question

```
{Stack trace: 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:588)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(AnnotationParser.java:239)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:229)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1016)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:1000)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getAtInject(InjectionPoint.java:468)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:653)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:358)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:377)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toProvider(BindingBuilder.java:106)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toProvider(BindingBuilder.java:43)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusTypeBinder.hear(PlexusTypeBinder.java:85)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusXmlBeanModule.configure(PlexusXmlBeanModule.java:91)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusBindingModule.configure(PlexusBindingModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:80)
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.MergedModule.configure(MergedModule.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:470)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:196)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)}
```

Comment: Your classfile is truncated. Restore from a backup, redownload(if downloaded), or recompile.

Comment: If you have a horrible or auto generated class, eclipse has a limit to how much code can be in a method. See the last answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497495/maximum-size-of-java-class-exception-table

Comment: Your question is lacking informations. Just a stack isn't quite helpful to understand the question.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau yesterday maven is working fine,,today it shows that problem,i tried backup also it does not work ,and for your information tomcat is working fine its a maven problem ,and I uninstall maven and all things before posting this question

Comment: That's the kind of informations you should add to your question, so people know what you've tried and how it got there.

Comment: @Augusto that is not the issue sir

Comment: @hexafraction I done that sir ,that not the issue,will any one face that issue

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Sir ,can you face that issue before ?,i tried almost every thing for working ,then i came here ,other wise i will solve my issue by myself,please help

Comment: Personnally, no but for others with the knowledge to help you, your question is not in a format that will help them. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau i edited the question Sir,please see Sir,if you have the knowledge please share sir

Comment: Please, update your question with relevant parts of your pom file and the goal that you are trying to call.

Comment: I faced this issue and realized that i was pushing the class file over to a remote server using winscp and the transfer mode was selected as "text"...Restored the mode to "Default" and the error went away...

Answer (score 6):

Clean your maven repository:

(By default in your user folder)

```
~/.m2/repository
```

Then perform a clean install so it download the dependencies again and recompile your entire project:

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: i will give it a try sir,and respond back tp you @anthony

Comment: that not help Sir,anything more that should help sir

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

means that one of the class file is corrupted. Try to run `clean` goal to do the bad classes cleanup before you run the `install` target. Or simply combine both the targets and do `mvn clean install` for your project.

Comment: it's not the solution sir , i have done it before posting that question

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your stac-trace that you are using reflection. Is the class working when you use it normally? Is it possible that when you use reflection, the class is unreachable or mis-used?

Answer (score 0):

After all the research and changing things, i found the solution,
I updated Maven dependency,it doesn't work,

I uninstall tomcat and Java and then reinstall it.

**And the error is that Java Jdk is corrupted due to some reason i Dont Know it why.....**

***and thanks all for your suggestions***