# netbeans javafx hello world sample

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I'm kinda new to Java, and I'm trying out JavaFX. I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and made a new JavaFX project. Netbeans created a sample "Hello world" app, but running it gave me this error:

```
Executing C:\Users\*****\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld\dist\run875675325\HelloWorld.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/752848266.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1073159910.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/670904707.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application helloworld.HelloWorld
Java Result: 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which is your Java version?

Comment: Can you append the code to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven is suddenly throwing error, Truncated class file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252775/maven-is-suddenly-throwing-error-truncated-class-file)

Comment: Hi. I'm using Java ver.1.8.0_20. I'm just running the code that NetBeans generates when you start a new JavaFX Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing in that stack trace is this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

Anything that says **Error** within a stacktrace points to really severe "environmental" kind of problems.

In your case: it seems that one (or more) of the class files that your IDE generates out of java source code is simply **corrupted**.

Try to to simple clean and rebuild your project.

If that doesn't help (which I would find rather surprising); then I am kinda worried that your Netbeans installation itself is somehow corrupted (so, me personally, I would then completely wipe that installation and try from scratch again).

Comment: Hi. I tried to clean and rebuild, but it still gave me the same errors. I didn't modify the code in any way. It's just the sample code that NetBeans generates when you start a new JavaFX Application.

Comment: Before re-installing everything, go to project properties and make sure the source format is JDK-8.  If that and clean/build doesn't work, you have bigger problems.

Comment: It is set to JDK-8. Guess I'll try reinstalling.

Comment: So I just installed JDK 8u111 and the errors went away. I'm not sure why, but it seems my previous JDK 1.8.0.20 installation was causing it.

Comment: Probably some kind of corrupted file somewhere. Thanks for the quick accept!