# Does AEM's HTML Template Language (HTL/Sightly) have a 64KB limit like JSP?

Tags: jsp, aem, sightly

We are aware the every JSP service file created out of a .jsp file cannot be more than 64KB. So people substitute file include with dynamic file includes such as `<jsp:include/>` or `<cq:include/>`

Does HTL have a limit like JSP of 64KB?

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168701/why-jsp-file-can-not-be-more-than-64-k)

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated than that, however yes, HTL template is getting compiled to Java class, and that Java class cannot have more than 64kB size.

For more details about class sizes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294998/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-java-class-file#:%7E:text=class%20file%20contains%20a%20magic,is%20limited%20to%2065535%20bytes.).

In my entire career I have never seen a template bigger than 64kB so we had to break it down to smaller parts. In fact, I find HTL and AEM components very useful to break down the complexity.

Comment: In my case its not easy. Every JSP has included a huge custom global.jsp and that too static include. Not just that all JSP variables defined in global.jsp are of page scope so if  a page wants to override that it can't as the next JSP will include global.jsp again and reset the values. There has to be an easier solution to this.

Comment: But these inclusions are dynamic, or static? In case of HTL, inclusions are always dynamic.